# How API Rate limits work?

Tags: evernote

I develop an app, which uses evernote integration. The app uses api calls for creating and sharing notebooks, and currently I have an issue with rate limits. Are there any approximate numbers for maximum requests per second or per hour for user ? To keep them in mind and try to avoid reaching this limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evernote doesn't disclose the actual numbers. You will need to handle the `EDAMUserException` with the `RATE_LIMIT_REACHED` error code. See [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/rate_limits.php) for more details.